# Error when I try to add a dateTime field to my table

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add a new "dateTime" field to my posts table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->dateTime('published_at');

        });
    }
```

but when I execute `php artisan migrate` I get the error :

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                     
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "published_at" contains null values (SQL: alter table "posts" add column "publish  
  ed_at" timestamp(0) without time zone not null)  




[PDOException]                                                                             

      SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  column "published_at" contains null values
```

What's wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried adding nullable() to the migration?

Comment: Could also set a `->default("0000-00-00 00:00:00")` value instead of `->nullable()`

Comment: @TimLewis `->default("0000-00-00 00:00:00")` doesn't work with dateTime type !! weird ! I get this error with postgres : Datetime field overflow: 7 ERROR:  date/time field value o  
  ut of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: @TimLewis solve it :)  Not all DB-engines can handle a date like '0000-00-00 00:00:00' so we pick a safe date, that's far enough in the past like '1900-01-01 00:00:00', source : https://github.com/bolt/bolt/commit/b4a56f274463e75bf485c5ba44c20962922ab614

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Glad you got it working! In the future, try to include your DB engine as a tag on your question; this one should be something like `[php] [laravel] [postgresql]`; the more specific the tags the easier for us to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table->dateTime('published_at')->nullable();
```

Why not use `$table->timestamps();` it makes a `created_at` column just as the `dateTime()` type does and also makes an `updated_at` column which is ideal for posts that may be edited.

Comment: I think it would actually be best to have both `published_at` and `created_at/updated_at`, since it's likely quite possible that a `post` can be created but not published.

Comment: I guess it's subjective because in my opinion if your app allows users to create posts then those posts are essentially published when you create them.

Comment: That's probably correct for ~90% of all applications, but yeah, really depends on the application. It's possible the `post` requires approval before it is `published`, so the date the record was inserted into the DB (`created_at`) wouldn't properly reflect this.

Comment: Yeah I need published_at because in my case it's different from created_at in the meaning... Thank you guys for the help.